# Python OpenCV template matching gives poor results

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to build a tool that would recognize poker cards from an online site.

I thought the task would be trivial.
Harvest all possible cards, paste them in one image, get an "unknown" card, run template matching on all_cards_image, harvest the points where it is matched, compare it to a dictionary with (x,y) = "Ah" and voila.

But template matching gives such hit and miss results, some single cards are not recognized at all, some single cards are recognized as 4 of hearts, 5 of hearts and 6 of hearts simultaneously. 8 of clubs is recognized as 8 of spades and so on. When no card is present then it matches the whole template image.

I could not find threshold that would lead to satisfactory results.

I am attaching the whole code as well as the images.

It is clear to me that I could go the route of recognizing only rank of the card, maybe on black and white image and masking the suits for color (blue, green, red, black) and then matching them afterwards. I was just hoping there is a simple template matching solution without jumping through hoops.

First image with all the cards (all_cards.jpg) in code:
[image]

Second image (random screenshot) with all other details changed to white so as not to make the image too big, named "Screenshot_to_test_card_recognition_reduced.png" in code:
[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

# defining constants for positions, card width and height in a screenshot 
CARD_HEIGHT = 59
CARD_WIDTH = 90
HORIZONTAL_SPACE = 5
HORIZONTAL_OFFSET_2 = 1463
VERTICAL_OFFSET_2 = 1047
FIRST_CARD_X = 955
FIRST_CARD_Y = 370
FLOPS_STARTING_POINTS = [(FIRST_CARD_X, FIRST_CARD_Y), (FIRST_CARD_X + HORIZONTAL_OFFSET_2, FIRST_CARD_Y), \
                        (FIRST_CARD_X, FIRST_CARD_Y + VERTICAL_OFFSET_2), \
                        (FIRST_CARD_X + HORIZONTAL_OFFSET_2, FIRST_CARD_Y + VERTICAL_OFFSET_2)]

# show image function
def show_image(img, title = "Unnamed"):
    cv2.imshow(title, img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


# INSERT FOLDER WITH FILES
saved_folder = "D:\\WinPython 32 3.4\\WinPython-32bit-3.4.4.6Qt5\\notebooks\\Named cards"

template_image = os.path.join(saved_folder, 'all_cards.jpg')
screenshot = os.path.join(saved_folder, 'Screenshot_to_test_card_recognition_reduced.png')


img_rgb = cv2.imread(screenshot)
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

CORRECTION_FOR_SEARCH_WIDTH = 0 #60
CORRECTION_FOR_SEARCH_HEIGTH = 0 #20

# LOOP THROUGH ALL FIVE CARDS FOR EACH FLOP ON 4 TABLES 

for point in FLOPS_STARTING_POINTS:
    flop_starting_x, flop_starting_y = point
        
    for card in range (0,5):
        
        start_x = flop_starting_x + ((HORIZONTAL_SPACE) * card) + ((CARD_WIDTH) * card)
        end_x = start_x + CARD_WIDTH - CORRECTION_FOR_SEARCH_WIDTH
        start_y = flop_starting_y
        end_y = start_y + CARD_HEIGHT - CORRECTION_FOR_SEARCH_HEIGTH
        
        template = img_gray[start_y:end_y,start_x:end_x]
        w, h = template.shape[::-1]
        
        show_image(template)
        
        all_cards_image = cv2.imread(template_image)
        grey_all_cards_image = cv2.cvtColor(all_cards_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        
        res = cv2.matchTemplate(grey_all_cards_image,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        threshold = 0.85
        loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
        for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
            cv2.rectangle(all_cards_image, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)
            
        print(loc)
            
        show_image(all_cards_image)
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is a bit more than hoping one function solving your problems. I feel it makes sense to split the problem. You might focus on detecting the cards individually first, and then, try to label it (e.g. 5 spades). I assume your resolution is same within the game windows, so you might focus on detecting specific rectangle size on the screen, and, then try to label these rectangles by using another approach (e.g. a neural networks model trained on each card). What do you think?

Comment: Just adding to @Prefect's comment to start. I agree you should start with individual card identification; using OpenCV to detect numeric values has been established in a way that can be very accurate. Rather than manipulating your function, look at the labeled training data you are using to train your model and make sure it scores well. 

I'm assuming are the face value cards as they have a lot of noise that makes it hard to isolate which card suit they actually may be. Maybe change your x,y coordinates to isolate the spade and letter values for a higher accuracy.

Comment: a few requests: Can you post a link to the game so that we can get sample pictures and try out our solutions on the real thing? If not, can you post more pictures (google drive links to get around the 2MB limit if you must) and post a colored png of the all_cards picture?

Comment: Just to clarify, OpenCV template matching is not scale/rotation invariant, so you may have to introduce your own way of dealing with it. This might be of help https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/26/multi-scale-template-matching-using-python-opencv/

Comment: Perfect I am trying to recognize individual cards. **
drewipson There is no model. It is matching one individual card vs. all cards. **
Ian Chu It is PokerStars, I could post more photos. I did not want to reveal screennames of other players and stats from HUD. **
Knight Forked There is no scaling and no rotation.

Comment: I see that your all_cards image is sloppily cropped, with some card images having black edges more prominent than the others. Template matching is really unforgiving. I would suggest you to make background for that completely black or maybe crop and paste the cards such that they all look identical except for their contents. Secondly, make sure that template test images you crop are cropped exactly in the same manner as the ones in all_cards. That should give you better results but might not still guarantee one threshold for all.

Comment: More accurate would be to do template matching independently for value and suit.

Comment: An alternative to using opencv, is [multi template matching](https://github.com/multi-template-matching/MultiTemplateMatching-Python), which uses opencv at the backend but is able to get better results because it can combine multiple templates of the same object and take into account the overlap of multiple results.

Comment: @Knight Forked I went that route and it works. Still I thought that template matching should perform better and shouldn't make me jump through B & W card only, suit only after filtering for color dissection of something as simple as a single card that is always of the same size and never rotated.